# Busybox locale not found

Tags: busybox

I install a Dockerfile from busybox but when I input "locale" or "locale -a", the command line return "sh: locale: not found".
How can I fix this?

Comment: you can't, busybox acts like a shell. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416715/package-manager-for-busybox